# Having problems getting a $_GET or $_POST to work with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

I have this code in my find.php file:

```
<select name="EmpName" required="required" id='empn'>
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>    
    <?php

    //get the employee id 
        $employeeId = $_POST['country'];

    //make connection to database, bail if no connection
    $connection = odbc_pconnect('db','','');
    if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed: " . $connection); }

    //retrieve usernames and passwords
    $sql = "SELECT EName FROM LoginTable WHERE EmployeeID='$employeeId'";

    $rs = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);

    while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $rowJobNum = odbc_result($rs, 'EName');
        printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $rowJobNum, $rowJobNum);
    }

?></select>
```

I have this code in my index.php file:

```
<script>
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}



function getCity(strURL) {      

    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
</script>




</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="" name="form1">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150">Country</td>
    <td  width="150"><select name="country" onChange="getCity('find.php?country='+this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">mg05</option>
    <option value="2">Canada</option>
        </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="">
    <td>City</td>
    <td ><div id="citydiv"><select name="city">
        </select></div></td>
  </tr>

</table>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the issue... I can't access the selection from the first drop down menu, the selection from the drop down menu is never going through to `find.php`. For reference, `mg05` in the drop down list is an employee ID, I am working off an example here that was originally formatted for cities/states etc.

Here's my big issue, if I go to:

```
$sql = "SELECT EName FROM LoginTable WHERE EmployeeID = '$employeeId'";
```

and change it to

```
$sql = "SELECT EName FROM LoginTable WHERE EmployeeID= 'mg05'";
```

It works perfectly, and returns the correct result. So... obviously the post of data from index.php to find.php isn't working and I can't figure out why. I have `$_GET` and `$_POST` working in other areas of my site, but not this one.

Any insight as to where I may have gone wrong? I've tried using both get and post and nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you tried changing `req.open("GET", strURL, true);` to `req.open("POST"...`? Also, make sure to escape your POST and GET variables before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are expecting the displayed text in the select to be post. This will not occur if the selected option has a value attribute, the value attribute will be used

```
<select name="country" onChange="getCity('find.php?country='+this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="mg05">mg05</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you!